# GitHub Xcode: Project checkout irregularity

Tags: ios, xcode, github, cocoapods, vcs-checkout

Me and my friend are trying to collaborate on a project that he recently uploaded to GitHub. I checked out the repository but do not get the same project structure after opening it in Xcode. The project contains Cocoa Pods which in Xcode appear as a separate file along with the main one. The problem is that when opened in Finder on my computer, the main project contains folders DummyApp, DummyAppTests and Pods together with some other necessary files as in the picture below.

[image]

When the main file is being opened in Xcode, only the Pods folder is recognised. The main project file is empty and there are no error message available to provide some clues. It seems like Xcode does not recognise the other folders as valid projects and excludes them.

We compared our folders locally in Finder, both have the same files and structures. So we've figured that the check out from GitHub works fine. We've been thinking that maybe my friend needs to invite me to collaborate on that project in order for Xcode to validate my participation but found nothing of this sort on Apples Developer sites. Any ideas what might be causing this problem?

The project has been re-uploaded to GitHub, re-opened, re-checked out and all that basic stuff..

[image]

Comment: Can you show the contents of your .gitignore file?

Comment: Are you opening the xcodeproj or xcworkspace?  Are there errors on the error tab?

Comment: @i_am_jorf Opening the xcworkspace gives the result mentioned above. I tried opening .xcodeproj file and it opened the main project but only it, without the pods available. It then gives one error  
`ld: library not found for -lPods-DummyApp-MDCSwipeToChoose
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` because the pods are not linked properly. The case mentioned in the original question gives no errors.

Comment: @thelaws .gitignore file is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learned that using GUI for gits causes more problems then it does good. Uploading just the podfile(via the terminal) and excluding all the individual pods solves the problem above.